# Is it possible to solve following question about integer programming using mathematica?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, inequalities

Consider a $5$-uple $(r,a,b,c,s)$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z},s\in\mathbb{Q}_+,r\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, denote $\frac{1}{2}(a^2-b^2-c^2)-\frac{s}{r}$ by $\Delta(\mathbf{v})$.

Let $A$ be a positive real number. What is the minimal value of $A$ such that for any $(r,a,b,c,s)$ with $\Delta(\mathbf{v})\geq A$, the following system of inequalities in $(m,n,l)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ always has solutions:

$$\Delta(\mathbf{v})\geq\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2-z^2)+x+y+z-\frac{3}{8}\\$$
$$\Delta(\mathbf{v})\leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2-z^2)+\frac{1}{2}x+y+z-9/8\\$$

$$\Delta(\mathbf{v})\leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2-z^2)+\frac{1}{8}\\$$

Where $x=-\frac{3}{2}-a+m, y=-\frac{1}{2}-b-n, z=\frac{1}{2}-c-l$.

We can solve a similar question :
Find minimal value of $\Delta(\mathbf{v})$ such that the following system of inequalities in $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}$ always have solutions:

$$\Delta(\mathbf{v})\geq\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2-z^2)+x+y+z-\frac{3}{8}$$

$$\Delta(\mathbf{v})\leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2-z^2)+\frac{1}{2}x+y+z-\frac{9}{8}$$

$$\Delta(\mathbf{v})\leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2-z^2)+\frac{1}{8}$$

$$y\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

$$z\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

By using the mathematica code:

```
 In[19]:= quad = (x^2 - y^2 - z^2)/2; Resolve[Exists[{x, y, z}, 

 delta >= quad + x + y + z - 3/8 && 

  delta <= quad + x/2 + y + z - 9/8 && delta <= quad + 1/8 && 
   y >= 1/2 && z >= 1/2], Reals]

Out[20]= delta >= 0
```

For this question, $\Delta(\mathbf{v})\geq 0$ is the answer.

But, in my previous question $(m,n,l)$ are integer numbers, I do not know how to solve this problem

Comment: In your Resolve command, did you try changing "Reals" to "Integers"?